# What's up with Guy Gardner's Yellow Ring?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

So I've been a Green Lantern fan for a while, and I know some of the history of Guy Gardner (everyone's least favorite Green Lantern not named Kyle).  I know he was booted from the GLC, found himself a new ring (which he referred to as 'gold'), before the 'Warrior' thing that happened.  I also know he eventually rejected the alien DNA that gave him his Warrior persona and powers, and was re-admitted to the GLC.

What I wonder, though, is where the new ring came from and if it worked like the other Yellow Rings we've seen more recently.

He had a Yellow Ring (though he sometimes called it 'gold') during the Death of Superman arc in the 90s, and was (like the rest of the then-current Justice League) useless against Doomsday.

[image: Hit Doomsday with your energy beams]

It's notable that his ring, as seen in the last panel above, doesn't have any markings at all - no Sinestro Corps symbol (since it was a decade away from being created), etc.

That said, he **could use** the ring, though Gardner has never been one to make people fear him.

So how has this been reconciled with the rest of the DC Comics continuity?  His ring obviously wasn't a typical Yellow Ring.  Where did it come from, how was it powered, and where did it eventually go?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### The yellow power ring worn by Guy Gardner belonged to the disgraced Green Lantern, Sinestro, once considered a legend among the Green Lantern Corps. It was created for Sinestro in the anti-matter universe by the Weaponers of Qward.

> When the Guardians of the Universe discovered that Sinestro, the Green Lantern of Sector 1417, had used his ring to take control of his homeworld of Korugar, the Guardians expelled Sinestro from the Green Lantern Corps and banished him to the planet Qward in the Antimatter Universe. On Qward, Sinestro met the Weaponers of Qward, and told them of the Yellow impurity, how the Green Lantern Rings could not affect anything colored yellow. Having been working on a weapon similar to the power rings for several millennia, the Weaponers of Qward developed the Yellow Power Ring, designed to project yellow energy and and take advantage of the Green Lanterns weakness.

- Gardner came into possession of the ring after he too was ejected from the Green Lantern Corps. During an identity crisis (and a series of attempts by writers to differentiate Guy Gardner from Hal Jordan) Gardner would discover he had alien DNA becoming Warrior and would for a time wield Sinestro's yellow power ring which drew its power from the conflict with Green Lanterns.
- Though the ring has no insignia (this was years before the Yellow Lantern Corps) the ring functions in almost exactly the same way, powered by will and recharged by interaction with the Green Energy. When Gardner used it there was no Yellow Power Battery, the ring was a weapon designed to siphon its energy from fighting Green Lanterns.
- Modern yellow power rings draw their energy from the Central Power Battery on Qward in the anti-matter universe. The modern rings have the ability to instill fear directly. It is unknown if the prototype yellow power ring Sinestro and Gardner used had this ability.

Answer (score 2):

After Sinestro was executed, Guy was removed from the green lantern corps, and asked Lobo to help him. Then he found Sinestro’s frozen corpse, got a green lantern to break the thing that he was trapped in, and took the ring.